# Do objects created in static class methods get garbage collected?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a static class that has some methods, somewhat like this:

```
static class MyClass
{
   public static string SomeMethod()
   {
       SomeObject TheObject = new SomeObject();
    
       return TheObject.SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

As you can see, the static method `SomeMethod` instantiates an object and then returns. When it returns, does the instantiated object `TheObject` get garbage collected or does it  get reinstantiated each time `MyClass.SomeMethod` runs

Comment: @ohmusama: how can the answer be "yes" when the question is "a or b?"

Comment: What actually happens is "a and b". The question is wrong, "Yes" is correct.

Comment: @frenchie A || B is YES Implies A is YES or B is YES, however in his case (the example code), yes it gets Garbage Collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any references to that object from any location that is accessible anywhere in code (called a GC root)?

No.

Then it can be GCed.

If there is some way for you to possibly get a hold of a reference to the object, somehow, then it cannot be GCed.

Comment: It might be worth noting the answer (correctly) uses "can be garbage collected" rather than "get garbage collected" like the OP.

Comment: But, WeakReference makes this not exactly true ;)

Comment: True, but it's still pretty explicit at that point why not, so it's not really worth qualifying every single GC related comment about it, in the same way that virtually anything you you ever say about C# can be violated through `unsafe` code.

Answer (score 1):

> When it returns, does the instantiated object TheObject get garbage collected or does it get 
>   reinstantiated each time MyClass.SomeMethod runs?

- It can be GC'd as there are no static references (unless obviously the method taking it puts it somewhere).
- NOTHING ever reinstantiated. New is new - it is not "NewOrReuse".

Comment: Well, except `new string(new char[0])`. For some bizarre reason, that *is* reused. At least in the Microsoft CLR.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Is that because Microsoft's implementation is automatically interning the string? I'm legitimately curious.

Comment: @AdamSears: I really don't know. It doesn't happen with other strings, nor even empty strings created in other ways. It's one of those curious bits of trivia that I enjoy collecting :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I shall put that in my bucket of knowledge as well. :)

Comment: Hi Jon. How do you know the it is reused?  is it like constant strings having the same value and thus the same instance?

Comment: How did you check? Did you use Object.ReferenceEquals(tcA, tcB)); ? THat is the only way to check reference equality with strings as == is - overridden to check for content.

Answer (score 0):

`TheObject` is a local variable containing a reference to a `SomeObject` instance. A new instance is allocated each time the method runs.

Assuming that that reference stays local to the method call (meaning that there are no external references to the object reference at the end of the method call), the object instance located by that reference becomes eligible for garbage collections when the method returns.

Which is not to say that it is immediately garbage collected. It is **eligible** for garbage collection. If memory contention is low, each such instance allocated could [theoretically] hang around for the duration of the process.